# Equation variable transfer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, equation, algebra, exponential, equation-solving

I've been working with the `algebra.js` JavaScript library for a while and I can't find an answer to my problem.
I have a number of equations that varies in type;
`(Linear, Radical, Quadratic, and Exponential)`
And I need to switch the sides of two or more variables.
An example to the solution would be in a `linear equation` as follows:

```
x = 2y - 6 ----> y = (x/2) + 3
```

This simple example works because the x is in the simplest form and the equation is linear. However, when the equation looks like this:
`7a + 4b = 9c + 5d` 
and I want to move the 9c to the left in order for it to look like this:
`9c = 7a + 4b - 5d`
It can't be done.

Moreover, these are all linear examples which makes them simple to process without using the library. But when it comes to an equation that looks like this:
`y = z*(a^x)*b^(1-x)`
and I want the left side to be (a^x), it doesn't seem that there is a way to do it.

**So, is there any way to transfer a variable or a term to be alone in one side of the equation regardless to solving an equation?**
It doesn't have to be algebra.js. It can be any library or code using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read thru algebra.js documentation already? There is a direct statement how to do this -- see [*solve linear equation*](http://algebra.js.org/#equations-linear) chapter, *multiple variables* subchapter, and its example:

```
var eq = new Equation(...)
var xAnswer = eq.solveFor("x");
var yAnswer = eq.solveFor("y");
```

Same `solveFor()` applies to other equation types as well.

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to solve the equation for a variable. The question is better explained now.

Comment: When you apply `eq.solveFor("c")` on `7a + 4b = 9c + 5d` you will get `c` as left-side but you want `9c`? I do not see a way to stop library from simplifying expression *too much* or solving it completely.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the library will try to solve the equation and as mentioned, the equations that I have are not all linear. As a matter of fact most of them are not. So, if I try to solve this equation `7a^2 + 4b = 9c^2 * 5d^3` for the `c` variable, it is going to give an error because it can't be solved. Instead, asking for putting one term `9c^2` is an easier process but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it using existing libraries to get this result: `9c^2 = (7a^2 + 4b)/5d^3`